# Simple rebase of entire git branch the correct way

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am trying to rebase an entire branch back onto master.
Master has passed my first branch commit by several new commits.
Currently, I use `git reset HEAD~<X>` to create 1 commit out of the entire branch, I unstage my branch, then commit it to a separate temporary branch/stash it and then rebase it on top of master. Is there a better way?

Comment: Are your sure you want to rewrite history of the master branch? Why don't you merge the other branch into master? Why don't you rebase the other branch with master and merge and then merge in back into master?

Comment: Or to ask differently: Why are you trying to "rebase an entire branch back onto master"? What issue are you having?

Comment: why not `git rebase master` while being in your branch?

Comment: I wish to put my changes only on top of the master.

Comment: If something changed on master during my work on the branch (other files), i do not wish to touch those changes at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have following options. From your question, I think maybe you want the *Merge + squash feature branch into master* option, since this will lead to a new commit on `master` containing all the changes you made on `feature` branch and it seems that is what you want to achieve, but I explain other options too, just in case you prefer another approach.

## Merge `feature` branch into `master`

```
git checkout master
git merge feature
```

## Merge `feature` branch into `master` after incorporating `master` branch changes into `feature` branch

```
git checkout feature
git merge master
# Resolve merge conflicts if needed & git commit
git push
git checkout master
git merge feature
# Conflicts are not possible here, 
# since they would have been already resolved in previous merge
git push
```

## Merge + squash `feature` branch into `master`.

This creates a new commit on `master` containing all changes you are incorporating from `feature` branch. Disadvantage: `feature` branch commits don't appear to be contained in `master` branch.

```
git checkout master
git merge --squash feature
git commit
git push
```

## Rebase entire `feature` branch on `master`

Disadvantages:

1. All commits of `feature` branch are rewritten on top of master branch. Therefore commits of `feature` branch won't appear as contained in `master` branch after the rebase.
2. You eventually will have to resolve *merge* conflicts more than one time in different commits.
3. You loose history and you'll see al the commits of the `feature` branch in one line

So, consider one of the above options.

```
git co master
git rebase feature
git push
```

## Squash `feature` branch and then merge it into `master`.

Disadvantage: You need to rewrite remote history if your `feature` branch is already pushed to remote. This is usually not advisable. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55824162/6939011 for more details